# Python - Reading CSV directly from Windows Network drive

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

In Python2, I am trying to read a basic csv directly from windows network drive.
Code is as below -

```
with open(r'\\dfs_name\base_folder\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\file_name.csv','rb') as configFile:
```

However, I keep getting error due to `\\` getting converted to `\\\\` and `\` converted to `\\`.

```
Error - 
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\dfs_name\\base_folder\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\folder4\\file_name.csv'
```

Can someone please help me understand whats the problem here and how to fix it.

Comment: If I run `with open(r'\\server_name\folders\filename') as f`, it works fine.

Comment: Forward slashes also work, so `//server/share/folder/file.ext` will work too.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't see the difference of your success and fail case.  In short, `\ ` are not "converted".  It is simply character escaping when Python is showing the string.  `\\\\dfs_name` simply means two backslashes, followed by `dfs_name`

Comment: Seems to be some strange issue with my python setup. Because the same script when used on my QA environment, it runs as expected.